# dependency injection (CDI) in java EE 8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I ve been looking into CDI to simplify the code, and I ve been trying to use it with Java EE 8. I an trying to replicate an existing exemple without success. I was wondering if anyone might have experienced the same issue:

**The PoolManager Class:**

```
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class PoolManager {

    private Queue<Object> pooledObjects;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        pooledObjects = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>(1_000);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            pooledObjects.offer(i);
        }   
    }


    public void returnObject(Object o) {
        pooledObjects.offer(o);
    }

    public Object borrowObject() {
        return pooledObjects.poll();
    }
}
```

the UsePoolManager Class:

```
public class UsePoolManager {

    @Inject 
    private PoolManager poolManager;

    public void usePooledObject() {
        Object object = this.poolManager.borrowObject();
        System.out.println(object);
    }

}
```

and the Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        UsePoolManager user = new UsePoolManager();
        user.usePooledObject();
    }
}
```

The injection doesn t seem to be working at all at runtime. I have no beans xml (i understand it is not necessary, and adding it didnt change anything.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Checking whether I am using SE or EE for clarification...

Comment: You mean CDI, I guess.

Comment: How are you running this?  You say EE 8 but then have a `main()`.

Comment: Using jre.1.8.0_141 - debuggin in Eclipse with a Main - I have been using java for a few months, not a specialist, but I installed the EE version.. - I also added in gradle the following dependencies if it helps..:                               
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject
 compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api
 compile group: 'javax.ejb', name: 'javax.ejb-api', version: '3.2.2'

Comment: I am indeed using SE not EE. thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run that in JavaEE container like JBoss or Tomcat, not like standalone JavaSE application (with `publis static void main`)

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss. I am looking at CDI 2 also just in case. Is it a good alternative. Not sure I want to move to EE for the moment, but I like the way patterns are handled in EE...please let me know if it s bad idea.. Otherwise, I ll post a quick word on my experience with CDI 2 here for the sake of argument...Thanks guys!

Comment: Tomcat != JavaEE. Try a testframework like arquillian

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argumentation, using the CDI 2 container for Java SE:

in Gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.se/weld-se-core
compile group: 'org.jboss.weld.se', name: 'weld-se-core', version: '3.0.4.Final'

public class CDI2Fire {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        SeContainerInitializer initializer = 
                    SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();

            try (SeContainer container = initializer.disableDiscovery().addPackages(CDI2Fire.class).initialize()) {
                container.select(UsePoolManager.class);
            }
        }
    }

@ApplicationScoped
public class UsePoolManager {

    @Inject 
    private PoolManager poolManager;

    public void init(@Observes @Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION - 100)
        @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init) throws Exception{
        usePooledObject();
    }

    public void usePooledObject() {
        Object object = this.poolManager.borrowObject();
        System.out.println(object);
    }

}

@Singleton
@Startup
public class PoolManager {

    private Queue<Object> pooledObjects;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        pooledObjects = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>(1_000);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            pooledObjects.offer(i);
        }   
    }


    public void returnObject(Object o) {
        pooledObjects.offer(o);
    }

    public Object borrowObject() {
        return pooledObjects.poll();
    }
}
```

Comment: One big note here - you are starting CDI container in SE which is totally ok and intended but beware! It's CDI only and you are using EJB annotations (`Singleton` and `Startup`) - those won't work as I doubt you have any EJB lite container started (and integration with CDI SE done, that's the part EE servers do). You will need to replace that with some CDI alternative.

Comment: Thanks Siliarus. I ll be careful to check for EJB annotations usage in the context of CDI 2. I ll be doing some reading: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/3.0.4.Final/en-US/pdf/weld-reference.pdf -

Comment: Otherwise, using the following dependencies in addition to the weld dependency seems to work for now for the Singleton and Startup annotations.. :  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject
 compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api
 compile group: 'javax.ejb', name: 'javax.ejb-api', version: '3.2.2'

Comment: It's not just about CDI 2.0...CDI in SE environment allows you to bootstrap CDI container and work within it. However, it does not do anything with regards to EJB container which is usually bootstrapped in EE containers. EJB != CDI even though the annotations are often used in combinations. While the dependencies will you mentioned will allow you to compile the code, the actual beans will not exist *or* will be `@Dependent` (e.g. as if you put no annotation on them from CDI-perspective) - the behaviour will vary depending on what bean discovery mode do you use. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you own answer: you changed the complete application logic by moving the business method call `usePooledObject()` into the initialization listener instead of calling it manually as in the original example.

This is probably not the best idea, as objects which wildly run on arbitrary initialization events are very hard to control.

Thus: the point that you probably missed is, using `get()` after `select()`:

```
try (SeContainer ...) {
    // replaces the original "new":
    UsePoolManager user = CDI.current().select(UsePoolManager.class).get();
    user.usePooledObject();
}
```

Further note, that the use of `CDI.current()` eliminates the necessity to have a concrete container reference in scope. Thus, you can use it everywhere in your application as long as the container is active.

Comment: I would vouch against `CDI.current()` as it can lead to pretty unexpected behaviour when used from an environment with complex class loading such as EE. There are many undefined parts and implementation difficulties in those parts. The container reference is there for a reason!